# Multiple Blazor apps, same hosting. Redirecting from the first app to the second. Azure App service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have asp.net core hosting app and two Blazor WASM apps. Similar like [this demo](https://github.com/javiercn/BlazorMultipleApps). Problem appears when I try to navigate from one app to an another. It works on local, but published version on Azure App Service (Linux) has this issue.

Second app is under `/SecondApp`, first app is under the root. (this is the difference form demo app).

Configuration:

```
app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/SecondApp",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), second =>
{
    second.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/SecondApp");
    second.UseStaticFiles();
    second.UseStaticFiles("/SecondApp");
     
    second.UseRouting();

    second.UseIdentityServer();
    second.UseAuthentication();
    second.UseAuthorization();
    second.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("SecondApp/{**any}", "SecondApp/index.html");
    });
});

app.MapWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/SecondApp", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), first =>
{
first.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
first.UseStaticFiles();
first.UseRouting();
first.UseIdentityServer();
first.UseAuthentication();
first.UseAuthorization();
first.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    //endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    //endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{*path:regex(^(?!SecondApp).*$)}", "index.html"); 
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{*path:nonfile}", "index.html");

});
});
```

In the first app I have a link to `https://localhost:5001/SecondApp`. When I click that it falls to first app with: `Sorry, there's nothing at this address.` When I refresh the page (Ctrl+F5) it loads second app without problem.

Again, I don't have this issue on local, only on azure. But I am not aware of any configuration that could influence this.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:
Maybe this is useful (?). If I specify fallback page instead of a file:

```cs
 endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("a/{*path:nonfile}", "/a/Index");
```

it throws:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /a/Index, area: }.

**BIG EDIT!**

After trying everything I turned off the `HTTPS only` option in Azure (under TLS/SSL settings) and it works.

I also created [demo project](https://blazor-multi-apps.azurewebsites.net/) ([github](https://github.com/tesar-tech/MultipleBlazorAppsWithAuth)) with https on, so you can see the error.

Comment: Take a look at an article I wrote about multi SPA hosting - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5287009/Blazor-Hydra-Hosting-Multiple-Blazor-SPAs-on-a-sin.  I'll have a look at your configuration in a while and see if I can see the problem

Comment: As an add on to the above comment, it definitely works on Azure - https://cec-blazor-examples.azurewebsites.net/.  Check carefully all you URLs, specifically the slashes.  I'm assuming you have the `StaticWebAssetBasePath` set and the base in the startup page `<base href="/red/" />`.  I also don't use capitals in the URLs e.g. secondapp instead of SecondApp

Comment: Your project was my inspiration on this route to multiple blazor apps. Big thanks for it! I had everything set up as you suggested. (even the lowercase variant). I see one difference between our apps. Your "Index" (root) app is the server one. All of your wasm apps are under `/something`. But my root app is wasm, same as the second one...

Comment: I made some progress, see the big edit. Probably gonna move to another issue.

Comment: I'll have a play later on my test sites to run the WASM as the root project and post what I found as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my 3 days of trying everything...

The catch was in this line:

```cs
 endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{*path:nonfile}", "index.html");
```

This is fallback for naked app... When navigating from naked to second app it falls to index, it does not map to `/secondapp`... So the solution was specify fallback only for empty page:

```cs
 endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{*path:}", "index.html");
```