# Cannot switch Blazor apps (under same hosting) when "HTTPS only" option on Azure App Service is on

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor, azure-appservice

I am having this issue with [Multiple Blazor apps, same hosting. Redirecting from the first app to the second. Azure App service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614745/multiple-blazor-apps-same-hosting-redirecting-from-the-first-app-to-the-second).

I have 2 Blazor WASM apps, hosted with asp.net core on Azure App Service. When I try to navigate from one to the other it shows the `Sorry, there's nothing at this address.`

You can try it here: https://blazor-multi-apps.azurewebsites.net (click on Second Client link). [Source code](https://github.com/tesar-tech/MultipleBlazorAppsWithAuth).

When I **turn off** the `HTTPs Only` option in Azure portal, this **issue disappears** and it works as expected.

It works fine on local.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `NavigationManager` with forced reload.

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

...

 NavigationManager.NavigateTo("https://blazor-multi-apps.azurewebsites.net/secondapp", true);
```

Not sure if this will work. But when I tried your site and navigated it seemed liked the initial app tried to route to an internal page '/secondapp', but if I pressed CTRL-F5 it worked.

I tried to live edit the `href` in the link to be absolute, that didn't work.
<s>`<a href="https://blazor-multi-apps.azurewebsites.net/secondapp" target="_blank">Second client</a>`</s>

Comment: Unfortunately no change after forced reload. As I understand routing in blazor- it should ask server about `/secondapp`  and server should return the second app. It returns "nothing" instead, like it doesn't know about the ` secondapp`...